# Why would you ever use Object#clone on a frozen object?

Tags: ruby

Okay, so just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you would ever want to use [`Object#clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-clone) on a frozen object? As I understand it, the only reason for using [`Object#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-dup) and [`Object#clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-clone) is to get a second copy of an existing object so that you can modify it without changing the original. But [`Object#clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-clone) copies the frozen state of the object, and you can't modify frozen objects, so is there any reason why you would ever want to use it in that context?

And on a related note, if there is no use case, is there any reason for this?

```
f = "Some string"
f.frozen? #=> false
f.freeze
f.frozen? #=> true
f2 = f.clone
f2.frozen? #=> true
f2.equal? f #=> false
# Why bother? You can't change f or f2 anyway, so
# why even copy it at all?
```

Comment: There probably is not any point, unless you need a new object_id for each use of the variables. But what are you trying to do? Have you seen a copy being made in code somewhere, and want to know if it is doing something meaningful? There are plenty of other "no point" pieces of code, such as `5` in `def whatever?; 5; true; end`

Comment: I think you should use `f2 == f` or `eql?`. Well, `equal?` returns false for not frozen strings too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes (in fact quite often) you may `.clone` a structure without knowing or wanting to know what kind of objects are in it, or whether they are frozen.

In this kind of scenario it is useful for frozen objects to behave similarly to their non-frozen counterparts, so that general expectations about how `.clone` works are met. To clarify, with `.clone` that includes preserving the frozen state (whilst `dup` does not preserve that in the copy). Preserving the frozen state ensures the copy behaves the same way - *not* being able to modify an object is an important property and behaviour.

In other words, if frozen objects did not do this, they might break or cause complications in Ruby code that used `.clone` to process generic structures. An example of this might be DSLs that build template structures that get `.clone`d when used, such as Rack response handlers generated by Sinatra, Rails, Grape etc.

Note I am not saying that these libraries *do* specifically deep clone route details, I have not checked. Just that they have DSLs that create copies of fairly arbitrary structures. They are the *type of system* that benefits from a general, consistent behaviour of `.clone` with frozen objects.

Comment: **Q:** why would you ever clone a frozen object?  **A:** Because you don't know it's frozen!

Comment: My expectation of `clone` tells me that that if I have string, I can modify it. From the Ajedi32’s example, `f` cannot be modified. In the other words, it breaks my expectations.

Comment: @DarekNędza: Why do you have that expectation? You cannot modify the original, if you tried . . . it is preserved state. If you need that any frozen state to be removed in a general sense, use `.dup`

Comment: In my opinion, in any language that we can modify things (e.g. `'st'.gsub! 's', '*'`), I guess some people want to modify some data (e.g. string). They don’t want to modify original so they want to clone it somehow. They expect that they can modify copy of original data and that original data will stay the same. Well, that breaks a  rule of **my** least surprise. ps. In the recent edit, you made good point about `clone` being *100% clone*.